# Python: Constructing & Printing matrices

Tags: python, python-2.x

I need to create a matrix that calculates the LCS and then print it out. This is my code, but I'm having trouble with the print function (don't know how to get the LCSmatrix values into the printing)

```
def compute_LCS(seqA, seqB):

    for row in seqA:
    for col in seqB:
        if seqA[row] == seqB[col]:
            if row==0 or col==0:
                LCSmatrix(row,col) = 1
            else:
                LCSmatrix(row,col) = LCS(row-1,col-1) + 1 
        else: 
            LCSmatrix(row,col) = 0
return LCSmatrix


def printMatrix(parameters...):
    print ' ',
    for i in seqA:
          print i,
    print
    for i, element in enumerate(LCSMatrix):
          print i, ' '.join(element)

matrix = LCSmatrix


print printMatrix(compute_LCS(seqA,seqB))
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
seqA='AACTGGCAG'
seqB='TACGCTGGA'

def compute_LCS(seqA, seqB):
    LCSmatrix = [len(seqB)*[0] for row in seqA]
    for row in range(len(seqB)):
        for col in range(len(seqA)):
            if seqB[row] == seqA[col]:
                if row==0 or col==0:
                    LCSmatrix[row][col] = 1
                else:
                    LCSmatrix[row][col] = LCSmatrix[row-1][col-1] + 1_
            else:
                LCSmatrix[row][col] = 0
    return LCSmatrix

def printMatrix(seqA, seqB, LCSmatrix):
    print ' '.join('%2s' % x for x in ' '+seqA)
    for i, element in enumerate(LCSmatrix):
        print '%2s' % seqB[i], ' '.join('%2i' % x for x in element)

matrix = compute_LCS(seqA, seqB)
printMatrix(seqA, seqB, matrix)
```

The above produces:

```
    A  A  C  T  G  G  C  A  G
 T  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
 A  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
 C  0  0  2  0  0  0  1  0  0
 G  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  1
 C  0  0  1  0  0  0  2  0  0
 T  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0
 G  0  0  0  0  3  1  0  0  1
 G  0  0  0  0  1  4  0  0  1
 A  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much! I understand now how you passed the parameters for the print function. I also see how that first LCSmatrix line for the compute_LCS function is needed.